# Why do I keep getting interrupted by a Device Management - Software Update screen? How do I get rid of it?

Tags: ota-update, samsung-captivate

Occasionally and frequently at inconvenient times (in the middle of important Angry Birds games) I get a screen that says:

```
Device management
Software update
Congratulations!
New software update for
phone installed.
Phone is ready for use

OK
```

I click OK and it goes away, but it always comes back. Is my phone really being updated this often. I doubt it. It always reports the same version, Eclair. Even if it was, I don't want to be notified like that.

How can I stop this?

Comment: Are you rooted, or have you played around with your phone settings at all?

Comment: No. Not rooted. I don't think I've made any unusual settings changes.

Answer (score 2):

That's very odd.  Normally there should be no auto-update of the device software, and other updates will require a reboot.  Try the following:

1. Hold both volume buttons and the power button
2. Wait until the phone reboots, keep holding
3. Release the power button about 1 second after the white text with your phone model appears onscreen, keeping holding the volume buttons
4. Recovery mode should appear
5. Select "Reinstall packages" or similar

Comment: I don't see Install Updates. I see Reinstall Packages (also Reboot System Now and Delete All User Data and Delete Cache Data) is that what you mean? At the bottom in yellow it says: update media, please wait... update media, finished # MANUAL MODE # --Appling Muli-CSC... Installing Muti-CSC Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, Reinstall Packages is what I meant.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Not really. Recently I tried to update my phone to FroYo and failed, so I got a new replacement phone. I lost all my apps and with it the problem. If it comes back I'll try your suggestions again. Thanks for your help.